# Laravel: hasManyThrough relation to get many to many table values

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `three table` relationship like below

> Countries -> (has Many)Provinces ->(has Many)Cities

I want to know is there any way in Eloquent to get all countries where 2nd child i.e. city has `status=active`

I know to find active cities for a single County through `hasManyThrough` relation helper provided by Eloquent. But i need to retrieve `all Countries who even has a single active city`.

Note: I don't wanna loop through every country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`whereHas()`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence):

```php
Country::whereHas('cities', function($query) {
    $query->where('status', 'active');
})->get();
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonas for reply, can you please tell me to how i can get provinces for a single country having same scenario?

Comment: Do you mean `$country->provinces()->whereHas([...])->get()`?